# How to use images instead of text labels with google charts API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm using google charts API. How to use images instead of text labels?

here goes an example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hdg6/

The main problem here is if i had a new element i would have to add manual a new image. Is there a way to swap label text for images?

For example, setting my array with a

```
  var array = [
    ['Name', 'Lead', 'Proposal', 'Opportunity'],
    ['John', 1000, 7000, 10000],
    ['`<img src="http://s13.postimg.org/up2b680dv/images.jpg"/>`', 2000, 3000, 12000],
    ['Ann', 2000, 5000, 12000],
    ['Steve', 6000, 2000, 10000],
    ['Rachel', 10000, 4000, 9000]];
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The API does not yet support using images in place of text for labels.

Answer (score 1):

I am faced with the same issue, I recommend that once the chart is drawn, you then replace in the DOM, so where you have the img src above, replace this with a unique reference for instance `up2b60dv` and then replace this with the code above with script.